# Determine the identity element and inverse elements of $3$ and $-2$.

Tags: group-theory

Determine the identity element and inverse elements of $3$ and $-2$.

Given an algebraic structure $(G,*)$ with $G=R-{1}$, the set of real numbers without the unit number and $* $ stands for binary operation defined by $a* b=a+b-ab$ for all $a,b \in G$.

My Attempt:

Let $e$ be the identity element. 
$$a* e=a+e-ae$$
$$a=a+e-a$$
$$e=a$$

What is this giving? I don't understand this.

Comment: Start with $e=e*e=e+e-e^2.$ Since $1$ is excluded, you'll have only one option for $e.$ Then it is not difficult to continue.

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, you should upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a very simple mistake:

$$a+e-a\neq a+e-ae$$
The product $ae$ is not $a*e$, it is $a\cdot e$, where $\cdot$ means standard multiplication in $\mathbb R$. There is no reason why $ae$ should equal $a$. So your second line in the equation should read
$$a=a+e-ae$$

and you can continue from there.